# "This" vs. "It" in this sentence

Tags: difference

I wrote this sentence:

> Content extraction is the process of determining what parts of a web page contain the main textual content, thus ignoring irrelevant items such as headers, footers, navigation bars, advertisements, etc. **It (or this ?)** has application **(or applications?)** in indexers and text summarizers.

Should I use "this" or "it", in general when I should use "this" after a sentence?

Answer (score 2):

I'll go with it because it refers to aforementioned Content extraction.

[Here](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/it-this.html) you can dive into it / this uses:

- We use it to refer back to things or situations that have just been
  talked or written about.  It does not give any particular emphasis.
- We use this or that to refer to something with special emphasis –
  indicating an interesting new fact has been mentioned.

Comment: It was a useful link, then I think it depends on the next sentence. for example I could say "This is a challenging task"

Comment: @Ahmad: Note that ***it*** in such usages always has to refer back to some specific *noun* previously mentioned. But ***this*** (sometimes, ***that***) can and often *does* refer back to either the entirety of the preceding sentence, or an "embedded" clause/statement *within* that sentence. But in your example, both ***it*** and ***this*** are effectively equivalent. Syntactically I would tend to associate ***it*** with the simple NP *content extraction*, where ***this*** might reference either the entire preceding assertion, or the alternative NP *the process of determining [blah blah]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, it was as useful as to be considered an answer, I don't know why sometimes people here prefer to make a comment rather than an answer!

Comment: @Ahmad: As I said, in your *specific* context it's not easy to identify different possible referents for ***this/it*** because the entire preceding sentence *equates* one "it" with another. So my comment here effectively *digresses* into other contexts where we could make a meaningful distinction between ***the thing being talked about*** ("it"), and ***some statement made about "it"*** ("this" [statement]).

Comment: @FumbleFingers your point about what "it" and "this" may refer was helpful to me and actually the answer. Then I can decide what I mean by each.